# GRUB Rescue During Windows 8.1 Clean Install

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, windows-8.1, grub

I was trying to install windows 8.1 (upgrading from windows 7) on my laptop, and in the process remove my Ubuntu partition. During the setup I deleted all existing partitions (windows and ubuntu) and tried to install windows on Drive 0. The install goes fine until it needs to restart, at which point I'm sent to GRUB Rescue. 
So far I've tried

- bootrec.exe /Fixmbr
- bootrec.exe /fixboot
- Using windows Startup Repair tool
- System Restore.

Am I going to need to reinstall Ubuntu to get this working properly?

Comment: Since you are upgrading have you tried to simply blank out the beginning of the drive and tring the install again. If your using an upgrade disk it might be leaving the bootloader(grub) alone thinking thinking it has win7 bootmgr. Otherwise try EasyBCD to repair the bootloader for windows.

Comment: I'm using a bootable USB with a fresh version of windows 8.1 Pro, no upgrade here. Not too sure what you mean by blanking out the beginning of the drive?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood when you said you were upgrading. I would try the EasyBCD its a simple program to resolve this type of issue.

Comment: @Chris: Try `bootsect /nt60 C:` (replace drive letter as appropriate).